# Running safe wallet for other evm chains

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core, account-abstraction

I am trying to run safe frontend $ backend for new EVM chain but not able to do so. Can anyone suggest the steps or suggest documentation to follow.

BTW I was following https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40795-supported-networks this documentation but was facing a lot of errors while running safe-transaction-service. docker containers suddenly stops and a lot...  I was able to run frontend though

So can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This are the GitHub repository (https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure) and docs you can follow (https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/tree/main/docs) to run the required Safe services.